# formula for probability of specific die outcomes

Tags: probability, dice

Roll some number, N, of the same kind of dice, say d6.  Picking a target outcome, say 1, what is the FORMULA to determine the chance of getting 1s as a result, which is to say, how many chances of 1 die outcome of 1 (1x1), how many of 2 outcomes of 1 (2x1), up to how many Nx1  -- the maximum number of 1s on N dice.

Obviously in the example above, there's 1 2x1, if both dice come up 1, and 10 1x1, a total of 11/36.

But what is the formula?  If I roll 4 d10 dice, what's the chance of getting 1-2-3-4 x1s, in the 10,000 possible outcomes?  Ok, there's one chance of 4x1, but for the rest of the outcomes, how do I calculate the number of 2x1, 3x1, 1x1?  I then can add these four to get the total proportion out of 10,000.  I assume theres a way to do this by formula though, but it is beyond me.

Comment: oooops, hit the wrong key

Comment: I roll 4x D10, and want to know how many combinations including 1s will come up. Roll 4 dice (D10)  as mentioned, you must solve this equation 4 times, with n = 1 trial for each, with p = .1 (10%) through .4 (40%).  To solve for k in this equation is beyond me, because working through the math you only get some factor of k equals the answer for each equation, and without knowing what k is you simply get an answer relative to k, but not an actual set of outcomes.  Without reference to a formula, it appears there's 1/10,000 chance of 4x1, 4/10,000 chance of 3x1, but then it gets fuzzy.  Help?

Comment: You’re using the formula incorrectly. $n$ and $p$ remain the same for a given number of dice. Only $k$ changes. I’ll expand my answer with more detail.

Answer (score 2):

You’re looking for what’s called the *binomial distribution*, which gives the probability of exactly $k$ successes in a sequence of $n$ independent Bernoulli  (i.e., succeed/fail) trians with a fixed probability $p$ of success. The formula is
$${n \choose k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}.$$

For your specific problem involving dice, $p$ would be the probability of rolling a one on a single die, i.e., $\frac16$ for a d6 and $\frac1{10}$ for a d10, $n$ would be the total number of dice you’re rolling, and $k$ is the number of ones rolled.

To combine different values of $k$, you add up their respective probabilities. There’s a special name for the sum of the probabilities from $k=0$ to $m$: the cumulative probability distribution, often written $P(X\le m)$. There are formulas for it that you can look up on the web, but I’m not convinced that for small numbers of dice they’re any easier to use than computing the individual probabilities and adding them up yourself. You’re likely not interested in including the probability of not rolling any ones at all in your sums, so you’d need to subtract $P(0)$ from the cumulative probability to get $P(1\le X\le m)$.

When doing these sums, you can save yourself some work by taking advantage of the recurrence $$p(n-k)P(k)=(1-p)(k+1)P(k+1)$$ or, rearranged, $$P(k+1)=\frac{p}{1-p}\frac{n-k}{k+1}P(k)$$ Note that $P(0)=(1-p)^n$.

Let’s work through your example of rolling ones on 4d10 ($n=4, p=1/10, p/(1-p)=1/9$): $$\begin{align}
P(0) &= (1-\frac1{10})^4 = 0.6561 \\
P(1) &= \frac19\cdot\frac41\cdot P(0)=0.2916 \\
P(2) &= \frac19\cdot\frac32\cdot P(1)=0.0486 & P(1\le X\le2)=0.3402 \\
P(3) &= \frac19\cdot\frac23\cdot P(2)=0.0036 & P(1\le X\le3)=0.3438 \\
P(4) &= \frac19\cdot\frac14\cdot P(3)=0.0001 & P(1\le X\le4)=0.3439
\end{align}$$
As a sanity check, the last cumulative value is $1-P(0)$ as expected.

If you want to compute the probabilities for rolling less than or equal to some value, then you adjust the value of $p$. E.g., to find the probability of rolling 3 or less on $k$ dice when rolling 4d10, you’d set $n=4$ and $p=3/10$ in the formula.

Comment: I'm not a math professional, and not a math whiz either, but as I understand the answer (which I REALLY appreciate), not wanting to sound dim...